# Is there any functionality like class="hover:shadow" exists in css or with Bootstrap or MaterialUI?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, material-ui, bootstrap-5

What I would like to do is to add an existing bootstrap class on element but I want it to be active on actions such as hover. I was thinking if there would be a parsing or functionality in html/css to be able to provide markup like `class="hover:shadow"` it would be super useful.
for table there is a class `table-hover` but having all these functionalities all accross library does not seem practical and maintainable.